# Batch Processing of Multiple Files in Multiple Folders

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm using the SoX sound editing command line tool. I'm trying to create a batch file that will allow me to drag multiple folders onto it and have the file process all the mp3 files within the folders, then output them into the converted folder, arranged into folders named the same as the ones originally dragged on. I currently have:

```
cd %~dp0
mkdir converted
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO sox %%A -c 1 "converted/%%~nxA" mixer -1
pause
```

This allows me to drag files on, but not whole folders. All I really need to do is take it up a level. As you may have guessed, I have very little batch processing knowledge so an explanation would be greatly beneficial.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to adapt this file to use nested for loops to accomplish what I wanted:

```
cd %~dp0
mkdir converted
FOR /d %%A IN (*) DO (
    IF EXIST %%A/*.mp3 (
        cd converted
        mkdir %%~nxA
        cd ..
    )   
    cd %%A
    For %%B IN (*.mp3) DO (
        cd ..
        sox "%%A\%%~nxB" -c 1 "converted/%%~nxA/%%~nxB" mixer -1
        cd %%A
    )
    cd ..
)
pause
```

The code now searches each directory in the folder with the batch file, then enters the directories and processes the files within.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the passed name is a file, a directory or nothing. You might try this code, and adapt it to your needs

```
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
  IF EXIST %%~sa\NUL  (
   echo %%~fa is a directory
 ) else (
   IF EXIST %%a (
     echo %%~fa is a file
   ) else (
     echo %%~a does not exist
   ) 
 )
)
```