# Batch Drag and drop files and folders

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm trying to copy multiple files and folders from a drag and drop selection using a solution I think should look something like this:

```
mkdir newdir
for %%a in ("%*") do (
echo %%a ^ >>new.set
)
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%b in ('type "new.set"') do (
SET inset=%%b
call :folderchk
if "%diratr%"=="d" robocopy "%%b" "newdir" "*.*" "*.*" /B /E && exit /b
copy /Y %%b newdir
)

exit /b

:folderchk
for /f tokens=* delims= " %%c in ('dir /b %inset%') do (
set atr=%~ac
set diratr=%atr:~0,1%
)
```

I've tried throwing together code from the following examples but I'm stuck:

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-dragdrop.html

[Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files)

[Batch Processing of Multiple Files in Multiple Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012650/batch-processing-of-multiple-files-in-multiple-folders)

Comment: Do you can tell us where do you stuck? It would be helpful

Comment: Honestly, I'm just not smart enough.  I need the batch to handle files with special characters and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Handling of special characters with Drag&Drop is tricky, as doesn't quote them in a reliable way.

Spaces are not very complicated, as filenames with spaces are automatically quoted.
But there are two special characters, who can produce problems, the exclamation mark and the ampersand.

Names with an ampersand will not automatically quoted, so the batch can be called this way

```
myBatch.bat Cat&Dog.txt
```

This produces two problems, first the parameters aren't complete.
In `%1` and also in `%*` is only the text `Cat` the `&Dog.txt` part can't be accessed via the normal parameters, but via the `cmdcmdline` variable.
This should be expanded via delayed expansion, else exclamation marks and carets can be removed from the filenames.
And when the batch ends, it should use the `exit` command to close the cmd-window, else the `&Dog.txt` will be *executed*  and produce normally an error.

So reading the filenamelist should look like

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem Take the cmd-line, remove all until the first parameter
set "params=!cmdcmdline:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
set count=0

rem Split the parameters on spaces but respect the quotes
for %%N IN (!params!) do (

  echo %%N
)

pause
REM ** The exit is important, so the cmd.ex doesn't try to execute commands after ampersands
exit
```

This is also described in the link you refereneced [Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5370380/463115)